# Sum and Count by month, shown with last day of that month

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a transaction table like this:

```
 Trandate    channelID   branch    amount
---------   ---------   ------    ------
01/05/2019     1          2        2000
11/05/2019     1          2        2200
09/03/2020     1          2        5600
15/03/2020     1          2        600
12/10/2019     2         10        12000
12/10/2019     2         10        12000
15/11/2019     4          7        4400
15/02/2020     4          2        2500
```

I need to sum amount and count transactions by year and month. I tried this:

```
select DISTINCT 
   DATEPART(YEAR,a.TranDate) as [YearT],
   DATEPART(MONTH,a.TranDate) as [monthT],
   count(*) as [countoftran], 
   sum(a.Amount) as [amount], 
   a.Name as [branch], 
   a.ChannelName as [channelID] 
from transactions as a
where a.TranDate>'20181231' 
group by a.Name, a.ChannelName, DATEPART(YEAR,a.TranDate), DATEPART(MONTH,a.TranDate) 
order by a.Name, YearT, MonthT
```

It works like charm. However, I will use this data on PowerBI thus I cannot show these results in a "line graphic" due to the year and month info being in separate columns.

I tried changing format on SQL to `'YYYYMM'` alas powerBI doesn't recognise this column as date.

So, in the end, I need a result table looks like this:

```
 YearT      channelID   branch    Tamount   TranT
---------   ---------   ------    -------   -----
31/05/2019     1          2        4400      2
30/03/2020     1          2        7800      2
31/10/2019     2         10        24000     2
30/11/2019     4          7        4400      1
29/02/2020     4          2        2500      1
```

I have tried several little changes with no result.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with the following statement:

```
SELECT 
   EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Trandate), MONTH(Trandate), 1)) AS YearT,
   branch, channelID,
   SUM(amount) AS TAmount,
   COUNT(*) AS TranT
FROM (VALUES
   ('20190501', 1,  2, 2000),
   ('20190511', 1,  2, 2200),
   ('20200309', 1,  2, 5600),
   ('20200315', 1,  2, 600),
   ('20191012', 2, 10, 12000),
   ('20191012', 2, 10, 12000),
   ('20191115', 4,  7, 4400),
   ('20200215', 4,  2, 2500)
) v (Trandate, channelID, branch, amount)
GROUP BY DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Trandate), MONTH(Trandate), 1), branch, channelID
ORDER BY DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Trandate), MONTH(Trandate), 1)
```

Result:

```
YearT       branch  channelID   TAmount TranT
2019-05-31  2       1           4200    2
2019-10-31  10      2           24000   2
2019-11-30  7       4           4400    1
2020-02-29  2       4           2500    1
2020-03-31  2       1           6200    2
```